# MAGENTO: if product is in category A or in category B or in category C, then do this I

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, if-statement, magento-1.6

I am using magento 1.6. I am trying to show a picture on product page view when the current displayed product belongs to specific categories. If product is in category A, or in category B, or in category C... Then echo image.

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: I personally don't see why this got closed. Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrasing of your question leads me to think that you need to show this image even when viewing a product in a category that's not on your list. There are several options available using the `catalog/product` model. I think the most optimal one would be `getAvailableInCategories()`, so:

```
$yourCatIds = array(1,2,3...);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
    //show the image
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$curID = $currentCategory->getId();
$showOn = array(4, 12, 88, 99); // array of category ids to show image on

foreach($showOn as $show){
    if($show == $curId){
        echo '<img src="yourimage" alt="" />';
    }
}
```

Not been tested but should work.